# Node JS | Google Vision API | "Bad image data" when sending base64 to Google Cloud Vision

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-ml, google-cloud-vision

I'm experimenting with Google Cloud Vision API and trying to extract colors from an image.
The problem occurs when I try to send a cropped image to the Vision API and I get an "Bad image data" error message back.

- The Base64 I send to Vision API that getting the error is working
  when I send it to the client and creating an image or canvas.
- The plain URL that is getting sent to the server through a request
  (req.headers.imageurl) is working when sent to the Vision API.
- The images that is being created from the base64 from the server is fully functional when downloaded and uploaded to the "Test the api" at https://cloud.google.com/vision

Could it have something with some CrossOrigin problem? But then I don't get why I can't draw it to an canvas later on when sent to the client.

Thanks in advance for the help!

**The function for requesting and sending the Vision API request out of the cropped image**

```js
// Imports the Google Cloud client library
const vision = require("@google-cloud/vision");
const client = new vision.ImageAnnotatorClient();

const fetch = require("../functions/Fetch");
const imageEdit = require("../functions/ImageEdit");
exports.colorDetection = async (req, res) => {
  // Then you 'get' your image like so:
  await fetch.getImage(req.headers.imageurl, async function (err, data) {
    // Handle the error if there was an error getting the image.
    if (err) {
      throw new Error(err);
    }
    // Crop Image
    const cropSettings = JSON.parse(req.headers.cropsettings);
    const croppedImage = await imageEdit.CropImage(data, cropSettings);
    const stringify = JSON.stringify(croppedImage);

    const request = {
      image: {
        content: Buffer.from(croppedImage).toString("base64"),
      },
    };

    // // Performs label detection on the image file
    const [result] = await client.imageProperties(request);
    console.log(result) 
    const colors = result.imagePropertiesAnnotation;
    // const stringify = JSON.stringify(colors);
    await res.json(stringify);
  });
};
```

**The crop image function**

```js
const { createCanvas, Image } = require("canvas");

exports.CropImage = (data, cropSettings) => {
  "user strict";
  // Settings
  let cropLeft = cropSettings.startX,
    cropTop = cropSettings.startY,
    cropWidth = cropSettings.width,
    cropHeight = cropSettings.height;

  // Canvas
  let resize_canvas = createCanvas(cropWidth / 2, cropHeight / 2);

  //Image
  let crop_img = new Image();
  crop_img.src = `data:image/png;base64,${data.toString("base64")}`;

  function Crop() {
    const ctx = resize_canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(
      crop_img,
      cropLeft,
      cropTop,
      cropWidth * 2,
      cropHeight * 2,
      0,
      0,
      cropWidth,
      cropHeight
    );
  }

  if (crop_img && crop_img.complete) {
    Crop();
    try {
      const base64Img = resize_canvas.toDataURL("image/png", 1.0);
      return base64Img
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  } else {
    crop_img.onload = function () {
      Crop();
      try {
        const base64Img = resize_canvas.toDataURL("image/png", 1.0);
        return base64Img
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    };
  }
};
```

Comment: Any resolution to this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use my code given below. Basically you have to convert the image into base64 and remove 'data:image/png;base64' and pass the value into content key.

```
const getBase64FromUrl = async (url) => {
    const data = await fetch(url);
    const blob = await data.blob();
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
      reader.onloadend = () => {
        const base64data = reader.result;
        resolve(base64data);
      };
    });
  };
const base64Image = getBase64FromUrl('url').split(',')[1]

      image: {
              content: base64Image.split(",")[1],
            },
```

This should work perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Struggled with this for a a while. Turns out, removing the `data:image/png;base64,`
Sorts things out

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).